# QGIS, QField and PostGIS offline work

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, postgis-2.0, qfield

I am doing some testing on using QField to collect some data, I created all the layers on PostgreSQL, and prepare all my layers in QGIS, then export all the layers as offline editing.

The Issue, When I came back, I used import to sync my data, the software will start running showing both projects and when finished I found my project was not updated.

I opened the GeoPackage file on QGIS, and tried to copy my data all the fields were changed sequence, 1 step down.
How can I use QGIS, QField and PostGIS in offline mode?